# long or int values convert in 64 bit

Tags: c#

I have a problem in my visual Studio when i am running any program in VS 2008 and assign int or long to any number it is showing in 64 bit like i assign int i=0 when i debug it it shows me i=0*0000 it is converting it in 64 bit

Comment: O done it sorry  there is a option in VS 2008 Named  HEX which is accidentally checked by me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like it's *actually* showing it in hex - particularly if the "*" is really an "x".

Right-click on the watch window and uncheck "Hexadecimal display".

Comment: Could be locals or autos window also.

Comment: @Damien: Yes, it would appear in various places - I just figured giving *one* instruction would be simpler than choices :)

Answer (score 1):

I only have visual studio 2010, however it is likely either an issue with your debug display  settings or you have used a `long` (which is 64bits long)

No matter what the debugger is telling you, `int` (In C# which this question is tagged as) well always be 32bit. This is most likely a display issue.